# apt-get clear previously failed install

Tags: apt

so, everytime I try installing a package using apt-get it is also downloading previous failed install (previously I install dropbox). how to remove/forget latest failed install?

```
Setting up nautilus-dropbox (1.6.1-1) ...

Dropbox is the easiest way to share and store your files online. Want to learn more? Head to https://www.dropbox.com/

Downloading Dropbox... 11%
```

Answer (score 5):

In this case removing `nautilus-dropbox` using `sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox` will not work directly. You need to remove post-installation script of this package.

- Open terminal and execute

  ```
  cd /var/lib/dpkg/info/
  sudo mv  nautilus-dropbox.postinst nautilus-dropbox.postinst.bac
  ```
- Now remove `nautilus-dropbox` completely using

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge nautilus-dropbox
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a general answer on how to remove or forget latest failed install, but in order to remove your erroneous package you can purge it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and typing:

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox
```

This will remove the package and will make your problem disappear. However - you will not get the coloured files and folders inside nautilus for your dropbox content.

If you want to have the `nautilus-dropbox` package you could try reinstalling it by typing

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install nautilus-dropbox
```